# How to find adjacent neighbours using Python?

Tags: machine-learning, python, deep-learning, transformation

[Full problem description at stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78033145/2386113)

I need to find the adjacent neighbours (not necessarily nearest neighbours) to a given point in a multidimensional space.

As shown in the screenshot below, I need to get the adjacent  neighbours around the red point, irrespective of their actual distance.

[image]

**Problem:** I can only find the nearest neighbours algorithms, which do not return adjacent neighbours if there is unequal spacing for different dimensions as shown below:

[image]

**How can I retrieve the adjacent neighbours around a given point?**

Comment: [Cross-posted from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78033145/674487).

Comment: why don't you put the spacing on the same scale ? (standardize everything)?

Comment: @LucasMorin I posted the whole question on SO where the whole issue (and MWE) is described. Here I have posted on the simplified question. I can't use the same scaling because the points because the points will be non-linearly distributed in the multi-dimensional space with unequal spacing. The posted screenshots show linear distribution (more or less) to describe the problem and requirement.

Comment: What is an "adjacent neighbor" and an "immediate neighbor"?

Comment: its not clear wht you mean by 'irrespective of the spacing'. To achieve that you would need that spacing is equal along dimension. If the spacing is not equal the neighboring is correct.

Comment: Why not normalize your inputs to have mean 0/var 1 along all dimensions?

Comment: @BenReiniger: Meant the same thing. Sorry for the inconsistency. Updated in my post. With immediate/adjacent neighbours, I meant the neighbours which are immediately next to the queried point, irrespective of their actual distance.

Comment: @LucasMorin: That's correct. The spacing needs to be equal for a nearest-neighbour algorithm to pick the correct neighbours. And, that is exactly my question, what do people commonly do in such a scenario? What kind of transformation should I use to make the spacing equal?

Comment: @Karl: I tried to use L2-norm on all points but I did it in 3D, which made the results worse because L2 norm favours the dimension with larger spacing (square makes the bigger term even bigger). But taking your suggestion, I will try to normalize the values in each dimension separately.

Comment: The phrase "immediately next to" to me inherently involves the distances. I see in your example the points are in a grid; if that's what you want in general, then getting the three values around the point for each feature independently, then taking the grid on those, may be what you're looking for. If not, then we still need a precise definition of "adjacent" in order to help, I think.

Comment: @skm Generally what people do is to put all the values on the same scale (renormalisation). Even better, you can consider each feature 'scale' as an hyper-parameter and look what scale provide better result overall. The way to go is simple: rescale for the algo and use original data (or inverse transform) for the plots.

Comment: @BenReiniger By "immediately next to", I mean to choose the neighbours who are directly next to you (as shown in screenshot-2) instead of choosing neighbours-of-neighbours because they are closer (as shown in screenshot-1).

Comment: @LucasMorin As shown in my original post at SO, I am creating using a 3D meshgrid. My `x_values = np.linspace(-0.3, 0.3, 5)`, `y_values = np.linspace(-0.3, 0.3, 5)` and `z_values = np.linspace(1, 6, 6)`. For this simple example, could you provide a sample code. Currently, I am thinking of transforming each point by normalizing each dimension, and then using the transformed points to build kd-tree.

Comment: I have answered the question on SO. Having duplicate question like this is generally frowned upon.